# Create separate state for similar react children object in an array

Tags: reactjs

I have created a small social media app where there is a like button to like the post. When I press like on first button, second post's like changes color too which is state based.

Here is the code:

Likes.js

```
<LikedPanel
    posts_id={posts_id}
    person_id={person_id}
    toggleLikePost={this.toggleLikePost}
    liked={this.state.liked}
/>
```

---

```
const LikedPanel = ({posts_id, person_id, liked, toggleLikePost}) => (
<Panel onClick={() => toggleLikePost(posts_id, person_id)}>
    {liked
        ?
        <Fragment>
            <LikeIcon nativeColor={indigo[500]}/>
            <LikedText>Like</LikedText>
        </Fragment>
        :
        <Fragment>
            <LikeIcon/>
            <LikeText>Like</LikeText>
        </Fragment>
    }
</Panel>
);
```

---

```
toggleLikePost = (posts_id, person_id) => {
    // make api call and then setState
    this.setState(liked: res.data.liked);
};
```

---

> Update

Posts.js

```
const Posts = ({ feed, deletePost }) => (
<Card style={{ margin: '25px 0'}} square>
    <ContentMedia post={feed.post} deletePost={deletePost} />
    <Like liked={feed.post.likes.length > 0} posts_id={feed.post.id} person_id={feed.post.person_id} />
    <Comments post_id={feed.post.id} comments={feed.post.comments} />
</Card>
);
```

---

Newsfeed.js

```
<div style={{ maxWidth: '500px', margin: '0 auto', paddingTop: '20px'}}>            
{this.renderPosts(this.state.feed)}
</div>


renderPosts = (feeds) =>
    feeds.map(feed => <Posts key={feed.post.id} feed={feed} deletePost={this.deletePost} />);
```

It loads fine when I refresh. But when I click like on any one post, all the other like icon gets toggled and vice versa. I see that it uses the same state for all elements. Is there a way to tell react to have its own self-contained state for every post's like panel?

Comment: It seems like every LikedPanel has the same state "this.state.liked"? Of course, if they all depend on the same bool, they will all switch to the same thing.

Comment: When I loop through it, it shows according to what ever is the bool for that object. Why doesn't it update the same way?

Comment: Can you show all the source code for the component that is controlling those likedpanel?

Comment: Are you passing this.state.liked to all your LikedPanel's? Should you differentiate by post_id/person_id?

Comment: Put the toggleLikePost inside the component that uses it, not in the parent.

Comment: @KerryGougeon Updated the code with parent elements.

Comment: @CodyS I should in some way. I thought it would be self contained and hence did not.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing a boolean value `liked` that it used by all the like buttons to determine if they should be toggled you can store an array of the liked posts. Then you can add liked post id to that array and detect in your `LikedPanel` if the current post id is in the `liked` array.

```
<LikedPanel
    posts_id={posts_id}
    person_id={person_id}
    toggleLikePost={this.toggleLikePost}
    liked={this.state.liked.indexOf(posts_id) !== -1 }
/>

toggleLikePost = (posts_id, person_id) => {
    // make api call and then setState

    this.setState(prevState => {
        // add post id to liked array only if it's not added yet
        if (prevState.liked.indexOf(posts_id) === -1) {
            return {liked: [...prevState.liked, posts_id]};
        } 
    });
};
```